# Dart Error: error: import of dart:mirrors is not supported in the current Dart runtime _help pls

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
W/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate( 5229): A splash screen was provided to Flutter, but this is deprecated. See flutter.dev/go/android-splash-migration for migration steps.
E/flutter ( 5229): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(94)] Dart Error: error: import of dart:mirrors is not supported in the current Dart runtime
E/flutter ( 5229): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(177)] Could not prepare isolate.
E/flutter ( 5229): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/runtime_controller.cc(384)] Could not create root isolate.
E/flutter ( 5229): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(574)] Could not launch engine with configuration.

Comment: Please format your answer, it's hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,
'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart' and 'package:json_serializable/json_serializable.dart' imported in the dart file. Removing json_serializable package resolved the above error.